# a session project error in a PHP page？

Tags: php, session

Code:

```html
<?php 
session_start();
require "connect.inc.php";                           //如果提交表单就链接数据库验证
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
　　 // 使用从表单中接收到的用户名和密码，作为在user表中的查询条件
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id,username FROM user WHERE username=? and userpwd=?");
    $stmt->execute(
        array($_POST["username"],md5($_POST["password"]) )
    );

    if ($stmt->rowCount()>0) 
    {
        $_SESSION=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
        // 将用户信息注册进入session
        $_SESSION["isLogin"]=1;                    
        // 注册用于判断登陆的成功的session变量
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
    else
    {
     echo '<font color="red">用户名或密码错误</font>';
    }
    // session_destroy();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>邮件登录系统</title>
 <style>
     div span{width:100px;text-align:right;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    欢迎来到邮件系统：ｓｅｓｓｉｏｎ　ＩＤ <?php echo session_id(); ?>
    </p>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
   <span>用户名：<input type="text" name="username"><br></span><br>
   <span>密　码：<input type="password" name="password"><br></span><br>
   <input type="submit" name="sub" value="登陆"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id,username FROM user WHERE username=?
>   and userpwd=?");
>         $stmt -> execute(array($_POST["username"],md5($_POST["password"]) ));

in these lines has an error：syntax unexpected $stmt,
i use it with PDO ,I dont know where is the problem,that way of writting should be ok,isn it?

the hole project is here：https://github.com/he1986yuan/exercise.git
in the document named email

Comment: While re-formatting your code, I've noticed strange new-line characters. Please ensure that you add new-lines after comments. It seems to me that those asian(?) characters somehow break encoding. To test out my theory, remove all comments and try to run it again.

Comment: thankyou ，I have tried，but still dont work。theyre just comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
  if(isset($_POST['sub']))
  {                          　　　　　　　　　　　　//使用从表单中接收到的用户名和密码，作为在user表中的查询条件
// --------------------------====================
```

the spaces marked with  `=`  are not spaces (they are other utf8 chars): on my side, I have removed these characters and Syntax error disappears.

The  `=`  characters are [unicode 3000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm), an [Ideographic Space](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html).